# union eliminates rows from half of query when other half is null

Tags: sql, union

Can someone explain why if I run the query below, rows are not added correctly from the top half of the union?  I thought union only eliminated duplicates, not values?  If I make it union all, it fixes it, I'm just not sure why it's needed?  Thanks,jb

```
CREATE TABLE #c3 (idNbr int, idValue int, idP int);
insert into #c3 (idNbr, idValue, idP) select 1 , 1 , 1 ;
insert into #c3 (idNbr, idValue, idP) select 1 , 1 , 1 ;
insert into #c3 (idNbr, idValue, idP) select 1 , 1 , 1 ;

CREATE TABLE #c4 (idNbr int, idValue int, idP int);
insert into #c4 (idNbr, idValue, idP) select 1 , 1 , 2 ;

select rs.idNbr, sum(rs.id1Tot)idTot, sum(rs.id2Tot) idTot2 from (
    select idNbr, idvalue id1Tot, 0 id2Tot from #c3 where idP=1
     union  
    select idNbr, 0 idTot, idvalue id2Tot from #c4 where idP=1
    )rs  group by rs.idNbr

drop table #c3
drop table #c4
```

Comment: "not added correctly from the top half of the union" is unclear.

Comment: Please explain what your "*union only eliminated duplicates, not values*" actually means. What do you expect your UNION to produce and what you actually get?

Comment: Your records from the top half are identical.  Union All keeps them while Union only represents one.  Your bottom half produces nothing.

Comment: `idP = 1` is not available on `#c4`

Comment: Forgive me if I was unclear.  If I run the code above as is, my totals are idNbr=1; idTot=1; idTot2=0
But, if I use union all, my totals are
idNbr=1; idTot=3; idTot2=0

I don't understand why the "union all" is necessary?

Answer (score 2):

`UNION` puts all rows from two tables in one table and then removes duplicates from the result. It doesn't look only at the rows of the second table to find whether such row already existed in the first table.

In other words, when `UNION` eliminates duplicates it doesn't care from which table the rows came. The result of `T1 UNION T2` is the same as `T2 UNION T1`.

In your example the first table of the `UNION` operator has three identical rows.

```
1, 1, 1
1, 1, 1
1, 1, 1
```

The second table of the `UNION` operator is empty.

`UNION` puts three and zero rows together:

```
1, 1, 1
1, 1, 1
1, 1, 1
```

and then eliminates duplicates from this result, which leaves only one row:

```
1, 1, 1
```

Then you calculate a summary off that one row.

---

`UNION ALL` doesn't eliminate anything, so if you use `UNION ALL`, its result is three rows

```
1, 1, 1
1, 1, 1
1, 1, 1
```

which then go into the summary.

Comment: Thank you so much!  That explains it perfectly.  I had thought it only removed rows when comparing queried unions, not with the individual queries.  Perfect explanation.

Comment: You are welcome @JanetBarnett. You can upvote an answer if you find it useful. It is a way to say "thank you". You can also accept an answer if it answers your question / solves your problem. Accepting answers shows others that you've got a satisfactory answer / solution. If there are several good answers choose the one that helped you most to accept. If a question has answers, but none of them are accepted, it is usually an indication to others that existing answers are not satisfactory / not good enough / incomplete.